# how to clean irregular strings & organize them into a dataframe at right column

Tags: r, string, special-characters, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have two long strings that look like this in a vector:

```r
x <- c("Job Information\n\nLocation: \n\n\nScarsdale, New York, 10583-3050, United States \n\n\n\n\n\nJob ID: \n53827738\n\n\nPosted: \nApril 22, 2020\n\n\n\n\nMin Experience: \n3-5 Years\n\n\n\n\nRequired Travel: \n0-10%",
       "Job Information\n\nLocation: \n\n\nGlenview, Illinois, 60025, United States \n\n\n\n\n\nJob ID: \n53812433\n\n\nPosted: \nApril 21, 2020\n\n\n\n\nSalary: \n$110,000.00 - $170,000.00 (Yearly Salary)")
```

and my goal is to neatly organized them in a dataframe (output form) something like this:

```r
#View(df)
     Location     Job ID    Posted      Min Experience   Required Travel   Salary
[1] Scarsdale,... 53827738  April 22... 3-5 Years         0-10%             NA
[2] Glenview,...  53812433  April 21...  NA                NA            $110,000.00 - $170,000.00 (Yearly Salary)
```

(...) was done to present the dataframe here neatly.

However as you see, two strings doesn't necessarily have same attibutes. Forexample, first string has Min Experience and Required Travel, but on the second string, those field don't exist, but has Salary. So this getting very tricky for me. I thought I will read between `\n` character but they are not set, some have two newlines, other have 4 or 5. I was wondering if someone can help me out. I will appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can split the string on one or more `'\n'` (`'\n{1,}'`). Remove the first word from each (which is `'Job Information'`) as we don't need it anywhere (`x <- x[-1]`). For remaining part of the string we can see that they are in pairs in the form of columnname - columnvalue. We create a dataframe from this using alternating index and `bind_rows` combine all of them by name.

```
dplyr::bind_rows(sapply(strsplit(gsub(':', '', x), '\n{1,}'), function(x) {
   x <- x[-1]
   setNames(as.data.frame(t(x[c(FALSE, TRUE)])), x[c(TRUE, FALSE)])
}))

#                                        Location   Job ID         Posted  Min Experience 
#1 Scarsdale, New York, 10583-3050, United States  53827738 April 22, 2020       3-5 Years
#2       Glenview, Illinois, 60025, United States  53812433 April 21, 2020            <NA>
#   Required Travel                                    Salary 
#1            0-10%                                      <NA>
#2             <NA> $110,000.00 - $170,000.00 (Yearly Salary)
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thanks as always sir. But this code went right above my head tbh, you're just best. One question if you don't mind: what's `'\n{1,}'` Is that regex?

Comment: `\n{1,}` matches newline (`\n`) one or more times.

Comment: I added some explanation to the answer.

Comment: Oh, I see @IanCampbell. You guys are reducing my chances of getting hired in US. I will come back to Germany once I am done with my study hehehe.

Comment: @RonakShah, thank you sir! Appreciate for your time

Comment: Is the part that is tripping you up `x[c(FALSE,TRUE)]`? The key thing here is that the vector `c(FALSE,TRUE)` is being recycled along the length of each row to select alternating elements.